# NULL value in query_plan column from the sys.dm_exec_query_plan DMV

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, dmv

I've written a query to return data from the `sys.dm_exec_query_plan` DMV, but for a specific stored procedure the `query_plan` column which should contain a link to the XML version of the plan is `NULL`.

```
select
    qs.sql_handle
    , qs.statement_start_offset
    , qs.statement_end_offset
    , qs.plan_handle
    , execution_count
    , st.text
    , substring(st.text, (qs.statement_start_offset/2)+1,
        ((case qs.statement_end_offset
            when -1
                then datalength(st.text)
            else
                qs.statement_end_offset
            end - qs.statement_start_offset) / 2 + 1)) as [Filtered text]
    , qp.query_plan
from sys.dm_exec_query_stats as qs
    cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text (qs.sql_handle) as st
    cross apply sys.dm_exec_query_plan (qs.plan_handle) as qp
where st.objectid = object_id('myProcedure')
order by qs.sql_handle
    , execution_count desc
```

I've checked the documentation and indeed it says that the columns is nullable, but does not say anything about the reasons why its nullable.

[image: query information]

Although the procedure has been ran at least two times, my understanding is that the plan cache should have information saved about this stored procedure and its compiled execution plans, but this query returns `NULL`.

I've also looked in the procedure code to check if it has the `RECOMPILE` option both at procedure level and at statement level and it doesn't.

My next assumption is that the `query_plan` column is `NULL` because all of the queries from the procedure (and from the above result set) are either inserting or reading data from #temporary tables.

Is my assumption correct and is that the reason why no query plan is stored for these queries? Or is there possibly another reason?

**Update:**

I've checked based on @Shaky's comment if the procedure is `encrypted`, by verifying the value in `sys.dm_exec_sql_text.encrypted` and it's 0.

I've also tested my assumption that the procedure plan is not stored because of the use of temporary tables in the queries and for that I created a dummy stored procedure which stored the result in a temporary table and then displayed the data from that table and its execution plan is returned by my query.

Comment: Did you read in [BOL Doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189747.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) that *If the query plan that is specified by using plan_handle has been evicted from the plan cache, the query_plan column of the returned table is null.*

Comment: @Shanky Yes, but I ran the procedure, hence the `execution_count` column is > 0. The plan cache hasn't been cleared in the meantime, which is why I also considered the `RECOMPILE` option on procedure / statement.

Comment: AFAIK and have read [This Blog.msdn article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlprogrammability/2007/01/12/5-0-retrieving-query-plans-from-plan-cache-dmvs/) there is limitation with the DMV `sys.dm_exec_query_plan`.

Comment: @Shanky it's not because of encryption. I've checked that and the value in the `st.encrypted` column is `0`. I've also checked my hypothesis, that it was due to using temporary tables and it's not. I created a dummy stored proc, ran it a few times and its plan cache is being returned.

Comment: Did you checked the 2nd answer and Blogs.msdn link I shared. I was not talking about procedure sys.dm_exec_quey_plan not sys.dm_exec_sql_text

Comment: @Shanky You're right, that solved my problem. Thank you